# is_dir isn't picking up directories in other folders

Tags: php

As you can see the script reads $currentDir and puts it into $unsortedDir (all the directories and files) then the foreach loop gets rid of the "." and "..", then it checks whether it is a directory or a file, if it's a directory it puts it in a list called $isDir and if it's a file it puts it into a list called $isFile.

However, it isn't detecting the directories inside the admin@admin.com folder... it puts all the directories as $isFile

```
$user = "admin@admin.com";
$currentDir = "uploads/$user/";
$isDir = array();
$isFile = array();

$unsortedDir = scandir($currentDir, 2);

foreach($unsortedDir as $sortDir){
    if ($sortDir == "." || $sortDir == ".."){
    } else {
        if (is_dir($sortDir)){
            $isDir[] = $sortDir;
        } else {
            $isFile[] = $sortDir;
        }
    }
}

print_r($unsortedDir);echo"<br><br><br>";
print_r($isDir);echo"<br><br><br>";
print_r($isFile);echo"<br>";
```

This is the output:

Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => New folder [3] => pics [4] => screenshot (2).png [5] => screenshot (3).png [6] => screenshot (4).png [7] => screenshot.png [8] => Thumbs.db )

Array ( )

Array ( [0] => New folder [1] => pics [2] => screenshot (2).png [3] => screenshot (3).png [4] => screenshot (4).png [5] => screenshot.png [6] => Thumbs.db )

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_dir($currentDir . $sortDir)`